# VIM_APP_DIR environment variable on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: terminal, macvim, osx-lion

I am looking to enable my terminal with the MacVim/mvim command so that I can access macvim through the terminal.

Following directions, I have downloaded and unzipped the MacVim files.

To be able to access MacVim through the terminal, one requires to set the VIM_APP_DIR environment variable with the value being the location of mvim script or the MacVim path.

By attempting the following command:

```
export VIM_APP_DIR = "the filepath"
```

I carried out printenv and VIM_APP_DIR does not exist in the set of environment variables.

Now that sounds more like a problem within a problem. The problem is I am unable to find a way to enable my Mac OS X Lion to be Vim powered and the above was the recommended route towards glory, however leave glory, the actor wasn't even there (VIM_APP_DIR).

Comment: lol..."leave glory, the actor wasn't even there" - priceless !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're getting this from. All that is required is to put the `mvim` script in your path, e.g., `/usr/local/bin`, and MacVim.app in a "normal" location such as /Applications or ~/Applications. Full list here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/mvim (line 20).

Answer (score 0):

First, you may not have to set the VIM_APP_DIR environment variable if you put the `MacVim.app` bundle in one of the “usual” locations:

- `~/Applications/` (the `Applications` folder in your home directory)
- `/Applications/` (the main `Applications` folder on the computer)
- `/Applications/Utilities/`

It actually checks a few more locations, too: some relative to the location of the `mvim` script, and in a `vim/` directory under the described directories.

In most cases, you should only need to set VIM_APP_DIR if `mvim` complains like this:

> Sorry, cannot find MacVim.app.  Try setting the VIM_APP_DIR enviro
>   nment variable to the directory containing MacVim.app.

Second, if you have to set VIM_APP_DIR (because you keep `MacVim.app` in an “unusual” location), the value of the environment variable should be the directory that contains `MacVim.app`, not the location of `MacVim.app` or `mvim` itself.

For example: If, you moved `MacVim.app` to `/MyFavoriteApps/MacVim.app` and have `mvim` available somewhere in your PATH, then you would need to set VIM_APP_DIR to `/MyFavoriteApps` (not `/MyFavoriteApps/MacVim.app`).

Third, in *bash* (the shell you are probably using), parameter assignments must not have spaces around the equal sign. It should look like this:

```
export VIM_APP_DIR=/MyFavoriteApps
```

If the pathname has spaces or special characters, then you may need to quote it. Single quotes are a good choice because they represent a literal string (you can include any character except a single quote itself).

```
export VIM_APP_DIR='/My Favorite Apps'
```

Last, you will probably want to put this “assignment and export” in your shell’s initialization file to make sure the value is set in all your future shell instances. A good choice is usually `~/.bashrc`.